# Sum the rows in which another column has a given string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a function (not a google-app-script) that would allow me to sum all the rows of a sheet in which another column of that row has a given string?

For example

```
-----------------------
Name  | Points
-----------------------
Joe   | 10
Ana   | 3
Joe   | 6 
Joe   | 8
Ana   | 5
```

I would like to call some function that gives the points of Joe and of Ana

```
SUM_IF_FUNCTION("Joe") = 24;   
SUM_IF_FUNCTION("Ana") = 8;
```

Comment: totally a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

It was very easy

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5,"=Joe",B1:B5)
```

A is the Name column and B is the Points column.